# Intersection of two Unicode Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, unicode, intersection, hindi

Working of my program: 
1)from a file test.txt i search lines containing the word " साधु ".
2)After the searching for the line, I extract words adjacent to its Right and Left.
3)After appending these words to an array, I try to find the Intersecting words in those two arrays.

Comment: is this what you want `{' ', '\xa4', '\xa5', '\xe0'}`

Comment: intersection is `set(array1) & set(array2)` even with Hindi word-arrays, unless I'm missing something..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode your string to unicode with following code

```
mylist = map(lambda word: word.decode('utf-8'), mylist)
```

Though for intersection purposes, you don't need to decode it. You can just do

```
#considering you have two lists 'list1' and 'list2'

intersection = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
```

Comment: Sorry that doesnt work for me.   Can you show me how do i find intersection between these two arrays?  -  list1 = [1,2,3,4, ' साधु ', ' बालक ']
list2 = [1,3,5,6, ' साधु ', ' बालक ']

Comment: It is working for example you are mentioning, only you might be getting result as byte string instead of unicode object

Comment: @vashi result = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))

Comment: @hspandher, how do i get result in actual string (unicode object)?

Comment: @Dmitry.Samborskyi, the intersection works and it gives me result in byte string. How do i get the actual string?

Comment: @vashi Python 2x does not support unicode by default. So, if it is not a problem use python3, the solution would work perfectly

Comment: Otherwise you need to mess with decoding byte string to unicode object

Comment: @hspandher, can you tell me how to do that? I have added my code above.

Comment: Use codecs library to open file with utf-8 format and then use the solution in described